# One time nonce http digest authentication

Tags: http, authentication, nonce

I try to implement a one time none for HTTP digest authentication process. First of all I'm aware of the fact that the authentication is not perfectly secure. Please do not tell me to use something else. The authentication process is working as expected. When the user authenticate successfully I append a http Authentication-Info field with the next nonce. The browser in this case Firefox is not using this nonce for further requests.

```
Authentication-Info: nextnonce="06e8043d3fb8c26156829c4b55afd13040"
```

Why is the browser not using my new nonce for future requests? It still uses the old now invalid one!

RFC7616 describes the header field.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7616#section-3.5

> The value of the nextnonce parameter is the nonce the server
> wishes the client to use for a future authentication response.
> The server MAY send the Authentication-Info header field with a
> nextnonce field as a means of implementing one-time nonces or
> otherwise changing nonces.  If the nextnonce field is present, ...

RFC2617 describes the syntax in section 3.2.3

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt

[Edit]

Is it possible that firefox is not supporting this feature. If I search here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate
for the header field I can't find a result.

But it is listed as standard header flag here:
https://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nextnonce` is not supported in Firefox, not even `Authentication-Info` header.

The bug ["next nonce digest auth test fails"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=116177) was opened 18 years ago and it's still not fixed yet.

I downloaded the [source code](https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/65.0.1/source/) of the latest Firefox version 65.0.1 and searched the project. "Authentication-Info" only appears in `netwerk/protocol/http/nsHttpDigestAuth.cpp` as a comment, nowhere else.